# How do I get a dependency needed in one method only, using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I've registered my `FooBar` type with ASP.NET's built-in container.

I need an instance in one of my action methods. If I needed it in all of the controller's actions, then I'd inject it into the constructor. But I only need it in *one* action method.

So in the action method, I assume I could do this (untested):

```
var service = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(FooService)) as FooService;
```

But [the docs say](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#request-services) that is is a bad idea. I agree.

So what are my options?

Comment: Then this method is good candidate to move it to the own controller. And pass dependency through constructor

Comment: @Fabio Not in my case, no.

Comment: Then what is wrong with passing dependency through constructor of current controller if you stricted to use only one controller

Comment: Dependencies can be passed to the instance in three ways(what I know at this moment) constructor, method and property. In case of ASP.NET method and property not easy approach so you have only constructor. For example  if you make dependency a public property then you can set it in middle-ware only for this method - but this makes your code more complex to maintain

Comment: @Fabio Okay that's what I needed to know. I can't find proper documentation for ASP.NET Core container. They only talk about constructor injection. I hope there is a simple way to do non-constructor way.

Comment: "They" talk only about constructor, because ASP.NET create new instance of controller for every request. This mean that constructor is a best and only way to pass dependencies. So if you have controller where different methods use different dependencies then you can accept injection of all dependencies in constructor or separate method to different controllers

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think there is a way to do method or property injection using the dependency resolver. It's certainly a bad idea to start referencing the container as a service locator. Anyway, I don't really think there's any rule that says properties of a class have to be used in every method.

Comment: @moarboilerplate There's no such rule, but it results in messy code. I agree though that resorting to service locator is the worst possible option, which is why I asked the question. See answer below for method injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `FromServices` attribute to inject a dependency into an action:

```
public IActionResult SampleAction([FromServices]FooService fooService)
{
   // ...
}
```

> Sometimes you don't need a service for more than one action within
>   your controller. In this case, it may make sense to inject the service
>   as a parameter to the action method. This is done by marking the
>   parameter with the attribute [FromServices] as shown here:

See official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection#action-injection-with-fromservices

Comment: They upgraded the docs site, so I missed that! Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.